# How to display the total hard disk space in Kibana?

Tags: kibana

i was wondering, how do i display the total hard disk space and  how much is used in kibana? Help will be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Kibana doesn't really use hard disk space itself, that's reported by ElasticSearch. You can certainly query Elasticsearch manually if you want, but you can get a whole lot more by using Marvel to check the overall health and availability of your Elasticsearch cluster (including disk space).

http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/marvel/

Answer (score 0):

Marvel is not free. You can use free products in http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/community/current/health.html

We are using ElasticSearchHQ for calculate free disk space and elasticsearch health .(http://www.elastichq.org/)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you cannot display elasticsearch hard disk usage with Kibana. That information is returned by various APIs (e.g., [indices stats](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-stats.html#indices-stats), [nodes stats](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-nodes-stats.html)) which Kibana can't access.

You could regularly query the API at `/_stats` server-side, save the result to an index, then query that with Kibana. This is basically what plugins like [Marvel](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/marvel/) do.